# Error #1009 when the first choice is clicked (but working with the 2nd and 3rd choice)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Ok ive googled about this error and still cant fix my problem.

it was all going well. Im just copying the same codes and changing variable names for the first frame since the 3 frames basically has the same functions. But when i copied it to the first frame, i get that error.

Fla file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/domsbipbxwmyoje/100%20-%20Copy.rar

```
stop();

small.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,play1);

function play1(event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop("3");
}

medium.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,play2);

function play2(event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop("4");
}

large.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,play3);

function play3(event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop("5");
}
```

Thats the code for the first frame. Thats just a part of the code and not the whole. I feel like the error is in there. The medium and large are perfectly fine. i carbon copied the codes to the SMALL option but i get an error. I feel like i dont need to post the code for the frame 3 (where the error is happening) since its just the same with MEDIUM and LARGE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the name of your button next_btn1 is called in the script but the name on the timeline is next_btn.

Instead of running the movie (ctrl+enter) you can debug the movie (ctrl+shift+enter) try it it will change your life ;)